# Large external hard drive

Tags: hard-disk, server

I own a small cloud storage company and I was wondering what type of external hard drive/server I should purchase. I have considered [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/G-Technology-G-SPEED-Shuttle-0G05041-External/dp/B01LW83HZ5/ref=sr_1_7?srs=)
80TB one, but is there a better choice?

Comment: Some more information on your use case would be useful.